# Improve performance of SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I found this legacy SELECT statement which is performing very poorly. Btw, column ID is not a PK.

```
SELECT 
    A.JOB,
    MIN(A.ID) AS START_ID,
    MAX(A.ID) AS END_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.R) AS CNT
FROM 
    (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(copyfrom 20) PARALLEL(copyto 20) */
         COPYTO.ID,
         COPYTO.ROWID AS R,
         TRUNC((DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COPYTO.ID) - 1) / 500000) AS JOB
     FROM 
         T1 COPYFROM
     JOIN 
         T2 COPYTO ON COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
     WHERE 
         COPYTO.DATE IS NULL
         AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 COPYFROM
                         WHERE COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
                           AND COPYFROM.DATE IS NULL)) A
 WHERE 
    A.JOB < 1
 GROUP BY A.JOB
```

There are indices on T1 and T2:

```
create index idx1 on t1 (id, date);
create index idx2 on t2 (id, date);
```

It returns:

```
JOB,START_ID,END_ID,CNT
  0,     100,   200, 20
```

I tried to replace it with this SELECT:

```
SELECT A.JOB,
 MIN(A.ID) AS START_ID,
 MAX(A.ID) AS END_ID,
 COUNT(DISTINCT A.R) AS CNT
  FROM (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(copyfrom 20) PARALLEL(copyto 20) */ 
             COPYTO.ID,
             COPYTO.ROWID AS R,
             COPYFROM.DATE as COPYFROM_DATE,
             TRUNC((DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COPYTO.ID) - 1) / 500000) AS JOB,
             COUNT(CASE 
                     WHEN COPYFROM.DATE IS NULL THEN 1 
                     ELSE NULL 
                   END) OVER (PARTITION BY COPYTO.ID) AS CNT_NULL_DATES_FOR_THIS_ID
              FROM T1 COPYFROM
              JOIN T2 COPYTO
                ON COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
             WHERE COPYTO.DATE IS NULL                   
) A
 WHERE A.JOB < 1 -- <-- When removed I see 10 as JOB column value
   AND A.CNT_NULL_DATES_FOR_THIS_ID = 0
   AND A.COPYFROM_DATE IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY A.JOB
```

It returns:

```
JOB,START_ID,END_ID,CNT
 10,     100,   200, 20
```

Why original SELECT returns JOB = 0 but new SELECT returns JOB = 10 on the same data?

Explain plan of the new SEELCT:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                     | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                              |                            |    86M|  4222M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                                |                            |    86M|  4222M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   VIEW                                        | VW_DAG_0                   |    86M|  4222M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                              |                            |    86M|  5299M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|*  4 |     VIEW                                      |                            |    86M|  5299M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   5 |      WINDOW BUFFER                            |                            |    86M|  3394M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   6 |       PX COORDINATOR                          |                            |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   7 |        PX SEND QC (ORDER)                     | :TQ10001                   |    86M|  3394M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (ORDER) |
|   8 |         SORT ORDER BY                         |                            |    86M|  3394M|   817K  (1)| 00:00:32 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          PX RECEIVE                           |                            |    86M|  3394M|   765K  (1)| 00:00:30 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           PX SEND RANGE                       | :TQ10000                   |    86M|  3394M|   765K  (1)| 00:00:30 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | RANGE      |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                       |                            |    86M|  3394M|   765K  (1)| 00:00:30 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |             NESTED LOOPS                      |                            |    91M|  3394M|   765K  (1)| 00:00:30 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              PX BLOCK ITERATOR                |                            |    18M|   452M|  4756   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|  14 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL               | T2                         |    18M|   452M|  4756   (1)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 15 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | I_PK_T1                    |     5 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |             TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| T1                         |     5 |    75 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is not that new SQL executes slow but that it returns 10 for JOB column instead of 0.

Comment: Please post the `explain` output

Comment: Do you need whole explain output or part of it? I don't know how to upload a file here.

Comment: I see there is a confusion in the aliases used: for T1 in the main query is used the same alias as for t1 in the subquery, which doesn't look OK. I think it should be: AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 COPYFROM2  WHERE COPYFROM2.ID = COPYTO.ID  AND COPYFROM2.DATE IS NULL)

Comment: Looks like T2 is being table scanned. Is there an index on `T2.ID`? If not define one and retry the query. And change `WHERE COPYTO.DATE IS NULL` to `AND COPYTO.DATE IS NULL`

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you very much for your quick answers. Yes, there is an index on T2.ID. As I wrote above: create index idx1 on t1 (id, date); create index idx2 on t2 (id, date);

Comment: When you say "ID is not a PK", do you mean that the join predicate `ON COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID` will match **many-to-many** rows?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes

Comment: _it returns 10 for JOB column instead of 0._ - start with that problem. Then see if you still have performance issues.

Comment: I realize you aren't asking about performance but unless T1 is massive (billions of rows) that execution plan would probably be better if you used a hash join between T1 and T2. Try hinting it `SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(20) USE_HASH(COPYFROM COPYTO) */ 
             COPYTO.ID, . . .`

Comment: The query has barely any filtering predicate (`A.JOB < 1` does little for filtering). That means it's seleting a massive number of rows. It's bound to take a significant amount of time to run. What's the current response time, and what is your expectation?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, you're right. My current issue is not the performance. I am satisfied with current performance of the new SELECT. The problem is that the new SELECT doesn't work as expected. Expected behavior is exactly the same as old SELECT. Old SELECT returned JOB=0, whereas new SELECT returns JOB=10 on the same data. Why? I don't know what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: In the second query `DENSE_RANK()` is running over a reduced (different) set of rows. It produces a difference sequence of numbers for the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Often a NOT EXISTS can be rephrased as NOT IN, not because that is *inherently* better (a common myth) but to allow the optimizer to pick a HASH ANTI JOIN which can be useful for large data sets

So perhaps try something like this

```
SELECT 
    A.JOB,
    MIN(A.ID) AS START_ID,
    MAX(A.ID) AS END_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.R) AS CNT
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COPYTO.ID,
         COPYTO.ROWID AS R,
         TRUNC((DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COPYTO.ID) - 1) / 500000) AS JOB
     FROM T1 COPYFROM, T2 COPYTO  
     WHERE COPYFROM.ID = COPYTO.ID
     AND   COPYTO.DATE IS NULL
     AND   COPYFROM.DATE IS NOT NULL
     AND   COPYTO.ID not in (SELECT ID FROM T1 x
                         WHERE x.DATE IS NULL
                         AND x.ID is not null  -- in case not already declared for table
                         )
     ) A
 WHERE A.JOB < 1
 GROUP BY A.JOB
```